# Stratified sampling on images

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, data-science, sampling

I have a data science problem which has around 70k images already labelled across 20 different categories. Some categories have many images whereas some other have fewer images. This in turn results in an imbalanced data set and poor results (currently at 68% accuracy). After some research I found out that I need to do a sampling of the images (Image mining?) instead of selecting all the images. One such approach could be Stratified sampling. Question is how do I select images to optimise the training of the model? Any command line tool or open source code that I could use on 70k images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have imbalanced data so to deal with that, you can simply use a library called [Imbalanced learn](http://contrib.scikit-learn.org/imbalanced-learn/stable/%60%60)
This library is originally focussed for implementing SMOTE but later also implemented under sampling and over sampling techniques.
It is also compatible with scikit-learn.

Using this approach, will result in data resampling in a way that every class has nearly equal instances.

**Second option:**
You can simply pick equal number of images for each class and form training data. This may not boost your accuracy due to lack of proper test data but surely your model will become more robust and generalized.

Comment: Thank you Prashant. This surely helps.